# How to get non-DOM properties of HTML in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

Say a HTML snippet like this:

```
<div a_example = "x" b_example = "y" class = "z"></div>
```

What is the proper way to get the corresponding properties of **a_example** and **b_example** in Javascript?

Can xpath do the job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.getAttribute):

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("z")[0],
    a = elem.getAttribute("a_example");
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/BSG3g/).

But, as has already been mentioned, you should really be using HTML5 `data-*` attributes, otherwise your markup is invalid.

Comment: Thanks. Shame on me about forgetting this.

Answer (score 2):

Some browsers will add all attributes as named properties of the DOM element, others will only add standard attributes. In both cases you can get non–standard attributes using `getAttribute`, however such a scheme is not recommended.

It is common to use standard attributes and DOM properties and only use getAttribute where necessary as it is inconsistently implemented in different browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at HTML5 data attributes, here is a useful article: http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Reading data attributes from a tag is really easy, and a fallback is available for older browsers. An example from the article:

```
<div id="sunflower" data-leaves="47" data-plant-height="2.4m"></div>

<script>
// 'Getting' data-attributes using dataset 
var plant = document.getElementById('sunflower');
var leaves = plant.dataset.leaves; // leaves = 47;
</script>
```

Comment: thanks. I mainly use javascript writing userscript to modify page, so changing the HTML itself is not really available choice for me. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, it is as simple as saying:

HTML

```
<div id="testDiv" a_example = "x" b_example = "y" class = "z"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var attr1 = $('#testDiv').attr('a_example');
```

Comment: You really don't need an entire library for such a simple task.

Comment: @JonKoops I know. I was stating the obvious. There are ways to get this using the "traditional" ways too. I'll list them here.

Comment: I understand your position. I however think it is dangerous to give a 'just use this library' answer. It will make the person asking the question dependent on a library without understanding the underlying API.

Answer (score 0):

```
element.getAttribute(attributename)
```

This should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I agree you should look at data attributes and better ways to do add non-standard attributes, but here's a 'raw' answer to your question, but I wouldn't treat this as universally supported (or advisable):

```
    alert(document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].getAttribute('b_example'));
```